# how can I don't use page in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I write a api, the response like this:

```
HTTP 200 OK
{
    "count": 1023
    "next": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?limit=100&offset=500",
    "previous": "https://api.example.org/accounts/?limit=100&offset=300",
    "results": [
       …
    ]
}
```

But the pagination give me some troubled, so I don't want it return the page. I just want all the results in this api. How can I do this except set `paginate_by` very larger in view, is there other params to control it?

Answer (score 0):

I know how to turn off it,
just set `pagination_class = None` can disbaled pagination~